# Creating a view with notch at the edge in iPhone

Tags: iphone, view, custom-view

Is there any possibility of creating a view like the following image? I do not want to keep a image like that I want iOS native coding functionality to achieve these notches.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're not a fan of core graphics, and you don't want to use images? You're going to struggle to achieve anything other than the default appearance for your apps ;). If you don't like the CGPath.. functions you can use the UIBezierPath class instead.

Comment: @jrturton.. It seems i have to go to CGPath.. Thanks for your option of UIBezierPath.. Will experiment with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `UIView` background color to clear color from the code (or from the interface builder with alpha 0.0), add an `UIImageView` and use your image.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But i want to create the view with coding not assigning the image. Because i have to dynamically create the notch. image is not a option.

Comment: Well, then use Core Graphics' arcs to draw the notches.

Comment: I am not really a fan of CG. Could you just give me any link or some sample code relating to that arcs. it would be of great help.

Comment: [There you go](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2106/core-graphics-101-arcs-and-paths)